# How to Randomly Select a Date?

Tags: sql-server, random

I am using in a Bash Shell Script [this code for retrieving a random date](http://www.random.org/calendar-dates/?num=1&start_day=5&start_month=5&start_year=1970&end_day=23&end_month=2&end_year=2011&mondays=on&tuesdays=on&wednesdays=on&thursdays=on&fridays=on&saturdays=on&sundays=on&display=2&format=html&rnd=new).

Is there a way to do that also in Microsoft SQL Server?

I can imagine that through a single SELECT query and probably by calling a few functions that can be performed easily, somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, all you really need to do is decide on your date range, then pick a random number between 0 and the delta in days (+1), then add that many days to the start of the range.

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '19700101', @end DATE = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT DATEADD
(
  DAY, 
  (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)+1)), 
  @start
);
```

There are other methods you can use to achieve randomness, including `RAND()` and `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`. In my experience, distribution is not particularly fantastic in any of them, and [some will behave differently in a query than others](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/wrapping-my-head-around-rand-in-sql-server/), so they may or may not be adequate depending on your needs. I followed up on [a comment from Paul White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413860/sql-server-random-numbers-using-cte#comment25289327_17413860), but saw similarly poor distribution with the following query (of course quality of distribution is also a factor of the size of the range):

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '19700101', @end DATE = SYSDATETIME(), @r INT;
SET @r = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)+1);
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @r, @start);
```

Documentation:

- [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)
- [`RAND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx)
- [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx)

Comment: Impressive. Thank you for answering my question. I am really amazed when reading your articles. Quite an extensive knowledge base.

Answer (score 2):

The only true randomizing I have found within SQL Server is to take a table and order it by newid(). So in this case, create a table with the dates you want to be valid. Then

```
Select top 1 dt
from dt_table
order by newid()
```